# Yahoo Mail classifies Email sent from my account to myself as Spam

Tags: spam-prevention, yahoo-mail

I create a new account in Yahoo Mail. All was jolly good for a while until I (for some strange reasons) email myself a list of things to do. The email is sent successfully after asking me to verify by writing the CAPTCHA letters. I clicked on the Check Email button.

The email appeared in the Spam Folder.

...

I fainted and just recovered (after what seemed like a millenia!)...

Why would Yahoo Email classify an email sent from my inbox to my inbox as SPAM?

Is it nuts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A lot of spammers send spam with the sender marked as your own address, trying to fool the spam filters this way. Spam filters work in various ways, trying to classify emails depending on various criteria. The email you sent seemed somehow suspicious to the filter, so it marked it as spam.

You can try to change this behaviour by telling the filter that the email you sent to yourself is not spam. This may or may not work, as the filter's trying to do what it thinks is the best for the user.

Answer (score 2):

Every e-mail that is sent from a known web-mail system, is tagged with the IP address that your computer was having during it's posting.
Chances are that your IP address was within a suspicious IP range on anti-spam filters that Yahoo is using to fight spam.

I agree that it seems stupid of them to not whitelist their own servers, but if their system is not so advanced to uniquely tag each mail in a way that spammers can't mimic, then there is no other solution than what you see: Your own email coming back as spam. 
Until Yahoo finds a solution to it, try another web-mail service and see how it goes.

Here is a quick way to check out if your IP is reported as suspicious by spam filter databases:
[DNSBL lookup](http://www.dnsbl.info/). If you see too many red dots, then that's probably the reason why Yahoo anti-spam filter was triggered of. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Put your own email address into the [Yahoo! Address Book](http://info.yahoo.com/privacy/us/yahoo/addressbook/details.html). I think this may help you.

Comment: I did. I named myself as Who Am I (just for the fun of it) and it even then it sent the email to SPAM folder.

Answer (score 0):

I e-mail myself all the time to remind myself things and to send myself copies of webpages etc. I like my own e-mails to be mixed right in with other peoples' for maximum organization. It's like having an away from home desktop.

It seems like yahoo and other websites are not considering how important it is to users that they have the capability to email themselves. I hear Gmail users can't do it at all due to a change in policy. Just thought I'd post: PLEASE DON'T GET RID OF THIS FEATURE, YAHOO.

Comment: welcome to webapps @jack, please consider reading the FAQ (http://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq) because this is not a usual forum and this section here is strictly for answers to the OP's question. And as for the Gmail users, they can definitely send e-mails to themselves without problems..